# Echo inside echo PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to input wordpress contact form 7 in footer template only if post type is "single", and I also need some html code there.

```
<?php if (is_single()) { echo '<div><p>html</p><?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="1" title="contact form"]' ); ?></div>'; } ?>
```

I tried this but it gives an error. How can I make it work?

Comment: @qwe, can you please let us know, what error are you facing with your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have PHP tags between PHP tags. Concat the strings instead:

```
if (is_single()) { 

echo '<div><p>html</p>' . do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="1" title="contact form"]' ) . '</div>';

} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can write in this way,

```
<?php 
if (is_single()) { 
    $str = '[contact-form-7 id="1" title="contact form"]';
    echo '<div><p>html</p> '.do_shortcode($str).'</div>';
} 
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<?php 
if (is_single()) { 
    echo '<div><p>html</p>'.do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="1" title="contact form"]' ). '</div>'; 
} ?>
```